# Seeking the XPath of an XML-file

Tags: xml, xpath

I've an xml-file with this syntax:

```
<Analysis>
<BasicInfo>
<Info1>Hash Value:</Info1><InfoVale>AAAABBBBBCCCCCC</InfoVale>
<Info2>More than 1 found:</Info2><InfoVale>No</InfoVale>
<Info3>Save Time:</Info3><InfoVale>2016-11-25 15:38:30</InfoVale>
</BasicInfo>
</Analysis>
```

I want to index this data into Elasticsearch. I want to give an xpath to Logstash but I have trouble determing the path.

What is the xpath for: `<Info1>Hash Value:</Info1><InfoVale>AAAABBBBBCCCCCC</InfoVale>`

I want to get the data within the InfoVale-tags. I've tried the following in an online XPath Tester but I cannot find a match:

```
/Analysis/BasicInfo/Info1/InfoVale
```

Any ideas? I don't know which syntax to use even after viewing the W3Schools documentation.

Comment: As `InfoVale` seem to be a sibling of `Info1`, but not its child you should try to use simply `/Analysis/BasicInfo/InfoVale`

Answer (score 0):

Found an online xpath detector and this is what I was looking for:

```
/Analysis/BasicInfo//InfoVale[1]/text()
```